# Pageviews not showing up

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews

I have a page on my site that I know received a number of page views over a certain period of time since I had a facebook campaign redirect people to it and facebook's analytics showed me 1458 clicks on that ad. However when I go to GA for that page it list 0 page views for that same time period.

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure GA is correctly added to your page?

Comment: I believe that it is. The developer added the appropriate code.